# Laravel - Update eloquent model column based on condition for all calls

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following laravel eloquent model:

Name: Zone

Fields: id, name, name_en

`name` - the name in my default language
`name_en` - the name in English

I want that whenever I query this eloquent model (`e.g Zone::find(1)`), It will check which language the user is, and set the `name` to the right language. In this case, if my user language is `en`, it will set the name`to`name_en`.

The goal is to return the `name` property in the right language (if user lang is `en` it will take `name_en`, or default `name` otherwise)

What I'm looking for, is actually to run this code whenever I'm using the Zone model:

if ($user->lang_code == "en) {
   $this->name = $this->name_en;
}

Sure I can change ALL my APIs and do this, but I'm looking for a solution that will apply it to any place I'm using the zone model in my app, without changing each place manually.

Is there any Laravel place where I can execute such code after every query to my `Zone` model?

Comment: You can use Accessors: 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Nice, I have just read about it, But I have no access to the user instance there (which I get from the request)

Comment: You can get the current logged in user by Auth::user();

Comment: Works, awesome!

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using spatie/laravel-translatable package 
you can use it like this:

```
$newsItem = new NewsItem; // This is an Eloquent model
$newsItem
->setTranslation('name', 'en', 'Name in English')
->setTranslation('name', 'nl', 'Naam in het Nederlands')
->save();

$newsItem->name; // Returns 'Name in English' given that the current app locale is 'en'
$newsItem->getTranslation('name', 'nl'); // returns 'Naam in het Nederlands'

app()->setLocale('nl');

$newsItem->name; // Returns 'Naam in het Nederlands'
```

Translations are stored as json. There is no extra table needed to hold them,
you can even set a fallback locale

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Eloquent Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to do this.

Define a function `getNameAttribute` in your `Zone` Model as follows.

```
public function getNameAttribute($value)
{
    // get the user's locale
    $locale = Auth::user()->locale;

    // If the user's locale is same as app locale,
    // no changes. Just return the name as it is.
    if ($locale === app()->getLocale()) {
        return $value;
    }
    // If the user has a different locale,
    // check if there is a name matching that locale and return it.
    // If no matching name found, return original name.
    return $this->{'name_'.$locale} ?? $value;
}
```

Now, whenever you access the `name` property of a `zone` model, this function will return the appropriate `name` based on the *User locale*

*Works with PHP7.0 or above.*

*This approach supports more locales that can be added at a later stage. Or in other words, You need not modify this function to support new locales.*